# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type `int'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

To be accepted to the study I want to do, I need to make a game prototype. Specifically for this, I bought some upgrades for my pc so it can run Unity (So I'm using it for the first time)

I'm learning how everything works by following video guides. I'm currently following a guide to make a board game inside of Unity.

I'm exactly copying what the video shows me. In the video everything goes well. However, I got the following error.

> error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type `int'

I'm very new to coding and have tried multiple things to solve it, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
public class DiceRoller : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    DiceValues = new int[2];
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public int[] DiceValues;
public int Dicetotal;

public void RollTheDice() {

    Dicetotal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < DiceValues.Length; i++)
    {
        DiceValues [i] = Random.Range ( 0, 5 );
        Dicetotal += Dicetotal [i]; 
    }

    Debug.Log ("Rolled: " + DiceValues + " (" + Dicetotal + ")");
}
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rCSED1c8NU&t=1313s This is the video I used for reference

Comment: that line probably should read: `Dicetotal += DiceValues [i];`

Comment: If you are in Visual Studio and you double-click on the error message, it will take you to the line where the error occurred.  Then, if you look at the offending line, the error is usually highlighted.  If you move your cursor over things, it will usually tell you information like the type a variable is.  Don't worry, you will get used to tracking down your issues in no time (since you will get _lots_ of practice - as does everyone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant to add the element from `DiceValues` to `DiceTotal`:

```
Dicetotal += DiceValues [i]; 
// Here -----^
```

Comment: Thanks! it solved the problem! (I feel a tad bit stupid that it's such a simple mistake, but I'm learning :) )

Answer (score 0):

change `Dicetotal += Dicetotal [i];` to `Dicetotal += DiceValues [i];`

Answer (score 0):

One this line: 
`Dicetotal += Dicetotal [i];`

Your `DiceTotal` object is an int.
I believe you should change it to `DiceValues[i]`